# how can I return two collections with a cypher query in the neo4j .net client

Tags: neo4jclient

I'd like to return two collections in one query "tags" and "items" where each tag can have 0..many items. It looks like if I use the projection, it will assume a single collection with two columns rather than two collections, is that correct?  Is there a better way to run this search query?

I'm getting `"the query response contains columns Tags, Items however ...anonymous type does not contain settable properties to receive this data"`

```
var query =  client
    .Cypher
    .StartWithNodeIndexLookup("tags", "tags_fulltext", keyword)
    .Match("tags<-[:TaggedWith]-items")
    .Return((items, tags) => new 
    {
        Tags = tags.As<Tag>(),
        Items = items.As<Item>()
    });

var results = await query.ResultsAsync;

return new SearchResult
{
    Items = results.Select(x => x.Items).ToList(),
    Tags = results.Select(x => x.Tags).Distinct().ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1

*Scenario:* You want to retrieve all of the tags that match a keyword, then for each of those tags, retrieve each of the items (in a way that still links them to the tag).

First up, this line:

```
.StartWithNodeIndexLookup("tags", "tags_fulltext", keyword)
```

Should be:

```
.StartWithNodeIndexLookup("tag", "tags_fulltext", keyword)
```

That is, the identity should be `tag` not `tags`. That's because the `START` clause results in a set of nodes which are each a `tag`, not a set of nodes called `tags`. Semantics, but it makes things simpler in the next step.

Now that we're calling it `tag` instead of `tags`, we update our `MATCH` clause to:

```
.Match("tag<-[:TaggedWith]-item")
```

That says "for each tag in the set, go and find each item attached to it". Again, 'item' is singular.

Now lets return it:

```
.Return((tag, item) => new 
{
    Tag = tag.As<Tag>(),
    Items = item.CollectAs<Item>()
});
```

Here, we take each 'item' and *collect* them into a set of 'items'. My usage of singular vs plural in that code is very specific.

The resulting Cypher table looks something like this:

```
-------------------------
| tag      | items      |
-------------------------
| red      | A, B, C    |
| blue     | B, D       |
| green    | E, F, G    |
-------------------------
```

Final code:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .StartWithNodeIndexLookup("tag", "tags_fulltext", keyword)
    .Match("tag<-[:TaggedWith]-item")
    .Return((tag, item) => new
    {
        Tag = tag.As<Tag>(),
        Items = item.CollectAs<Item>()
    });
```

That's not what fits into your `SearchResult` though.

## Option 2

*Scenario:* You want to retrieve all of the tags that match a keyword, then all of the items that match any of those tags, but you don't care about linking the two together.

Let's go back to the Cypher query:

```
START tag=node:tags_fulltext('keyword')
MATCH tag<-[:TaggedWith]-item
RETURN tag, item
```

That would produce a Cypher result table like this:

```
--------------------
| tag      | item  |
--------------------
| red      | A     |
| red      | B     |
| red      | C     |
| blue     | B     |
| blue     | D     |
| green    | E     |
| green    | F     |
| green    | G     |
--------------------
```

You want to collapse each of these to a single, unrelated list of tags and items.

We can use `collect` to do that:

```
START tag=node:tags_fulltext('keyword')
MATCH tag<-[:TaggedWith]-item
RETURN collect(tag) AS Tags, collect(item) AS Items

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tags                                            | items                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| red, red, red, blue, blue, green, green, green  | A, B, C, B, D, E, F, G  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

We don't want all of those duplicates though, so let's just collect the distinct ones:

```
START tag=node:tags_fulltext('keyword')
MATCH tag<-[:TaggedWith]-item
RETURN collect(distinct tag) AS Tags, collect(distinct item) AS Items

--------------------------------------------
| tags              | items                |
--------------------------------------------
| red, blue, green  | A, B, C, D, E, F, G  |
--------------------------------------------
```

With the Cypher working, turning it into .NET is an easy translation:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .StartWithNodeIndexLookup("tag", "tags_fulltext", keyword)
    .Match("tag<-[:TaggedWith]-item")
    .Return((tag, item) => new
    {
        Tags = tag.CollectDistinct<Tag>(),
        Items = item.CollectDistinct<Item>()
    });
```

## Summary

1. Always start with the Cypher
2. Always start with the Cypher
3. When you have working Cypher, the .NET implementation should be almost one-for-one

## Problems?

I've typed all of this code out in a textbox with no VS support and I haven't tested any of it. If something crashes, please report the **full** exception text and query on our issues page. Tracking crashes here is hard. Tracking crashes without the **full** exception text, message, stack trace and so forth just consumes my time by making it harder to debug, and reducing how much time I can spend helping you otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough writeup.  One more twist: using option 2, how would I return the set of tags that don't have any taggedwith relationships with the items?  That is tags only if they match the index search and they don't have any items. The item collection would still return items whose tags matched the index query.

Comment: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#match-optional-typed-and-named-relationship

Comment: Impressive answer, @TathamOddie !

Comment: Testing it out, in the .net translation bit I am only seeing a CollectDistinctAs<Node<T>> method rather than CollectDistinct<T> .  I'd like to return a POCO object so didn't want a Node<T> result.  Am I missing the right method?  Should I just add a select projection to the end of it like CollectDistinctAs<Node<T>>().Select((node) => node.Data)

Comment: We can't just retrieve the data, Cypher gives us the full node. You'll need to project it away later.